# A doubt on setting up a non-informative hyperprior

Tags: bayesian, prior, uninformative-prior

Below you'll find a section of page 110, from [Gelman's 3rd edition Bayesian Data Analysis (BDA).](http://amzn.to/1YkWigB)

In the problem at hand, the observations and parameters are independent, $y_j\sim Bin(n_j,\theta_j)$, and $\theta_j\sim Beta(\alpha,\beta)$.

What's the point of trying to reparameterize first? Do they want a uniform distribution on the new parameters, and then see what they obtain for the old parametrization?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.